# Change vertical space in overset

Tags: spacing, amsmath, kerning, stacking-symbols, stack

How can I decrease the space in overset? I found this solution online, but it doesn't look quite like the original overset (note I know it is difficult to come up with a solution to handle all cases elegantly, but I have listed 4 common use cases that would like to look good)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} 

%overset spacing
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oset}[2]{%
  {\mathop{#2}\limits^{\vbox to -.5\ex@{\kern-\tw@\ex@
   \hbox{\scriptsize #1}\vss}}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs


\begin{document}
```

I would like it to work for the following examples:

```
Original 1: $X_n\overset{P}{\to} X$

Original 2: $X_n\overset{D}{\to} X$

Original 3: $X_n\overset{\text{$r$th}}{\to} X$

Original 4: $X_n\overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} X$


Testing 1: $X_n\oset{P}{\to} X$

Testing 2: $X_n\oset{D}{\to} X$

Testing 3: $X_n\oset{\text{$r$th}{\to} X$

Testing 4: $X_n\oset{\text{i.i.d.}{\sim} X$
\end{document}
```

[image]

The spacing around the `\to` seems off. Can you guys help me come up with a more robust solution?

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to vertical space? Tried fiddling around with the `vbox` size?

Comment: No i mean the space around the `\to` arrow looks off (i.e. horizontal spacing) also the font on the P is different.

Comment: You're looking for a solution that corrects the horizontal spacing of your symbol: I believe the command `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` comes very close to what you want.

Comment: I don't understand, whats the pair?

Comment: Never mind. `\mathrel` is better suited. See @Mico's answer.

Comment: See also the `stackengine` package, for setting either the gap or baseline shift between vertically offset objects.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get better horizontal spacing of the `\oset` macro -- specifically, to make its spacing the same as that of a "relational operator" (which is the case for `\to`) -- you could encase the macro's definition in a `\mathrel` wrapper.

To make the `\oset` macro usable for different symbols/letters in the base and superscript positions, it's necessary to introduce a third, optional, argument: the argument of `\vbox`. Its default value, `0pt` is suitable for single uppercase letters in the superscript position and arrows in the base position. For other combinations, you'll need to experiment a bit to find the suitable distance by which the superscript term should be raised; the values given in the example below may be OK for the selected math font (`newpxmath`). Different values will probably need to be chosen if you use a different math font.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\midrule' macro
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\overset' macro
\usepackage{newpxmath,newpxtext}

% new \oset macro:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oset}[3][0ex]{%
  \mathrel{\mathop{#3}\limits^{
    \vbox to#1{\kern-2\ex@
    \hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}\vss}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\text{with \texttt{\string\overset}}\\
\midrule
X_n\overset{P}{\to} X \\
X_n\overset{D}{\to} X \\
X_n\overset{j}{\to} X \\
X_n\overset{\text{rth}}{\to} X \\
X_n\overset{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} X
\end{array}
\qquad
\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
\text{with \texttt{\string\oset}}\\
\midrule
X_n\oset{P}{\to} X \\
X_n\oset{D}{\to} X \\
X_n\oset[.35ex]{j}{\to} X \\
X_n\oset[.45ex]{\text{rth}}{\to} X \\
X_n\oset[.6ex]{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} X
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*, August 2022: I've received a request to explain how one would have to modify `\oset` to `\uset`, so as to place the supplemental material *below* rather than *above* the arrow. Here's how I think it should be done:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\uset}[3][0ex]{%
  \mathrel{\mathop{#3}\limits_{
    \vbox to#1{\kern-7\ex@
    \hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}\vss}}}}
\makeatother
```

The definition of `\uset` contains 2 changes relative to the definition of `\oset`:

- `^` is replaced with `_` ("underscore")
- `\kern-2\ex@` is replaced with `\kern-7\ex@`.

---

An additional remark: The material below the arrow is typeset in `\scriptstyle` math mode; that's fine for single letters or symbols. For longer expressions, such as `i.i.d.`, you may want to reduce the font size a bit more. This may be done, say, by changing

```
X_n\uset{\textup{i.i.d.}}{\sim} X
```

to

```
X_n\uset{\textup{\tiny i.i.d.}}{\sim} X
```

I suppose this remark applies to both `\uset` and `\oset`. E.g., one may prefer the result of `X_n\oset[.3ex]{\text{\tiny i.i.d.}}{\sim} X` to that of `X_n\oset[.6ex]{\text{i.i.d.}}{\sim} X`.

Comment: Great answer, I have updated the question a bit, do you think you could come up with a good solution to handle those 4 cases I have listed? I tried tweaking the vbox argument but that didn't help much in the `sim` case.

Comment: @Benjamin - I've changed the definition of `\oset` so that an additional, optional parameter can be provided: the amount by which the superscript term should be raised (or lowered). The default value of the optional argument is `0ex`.

Comment: May I ask for the corresponding definition of \uset (for underset)? The naive idea of putting "_" in place of "^" is not working.

Comment: @D.R - Please see the addendum I posted a few minutes ago.

Comment: Thank you, this macro helped me a lot! But, I am still at pain to understand how to work in two places : what means the “vbox to#1”, and why is there a @ at the end of ex? I read @ is added in some local macros names, but I don't understand what it means with a unity.

Answer (score 9):

I came around `\lower` and `\raise` TeX "primitives" here at https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html. And manually lower and raise a box in the `\overset` works fine for me.

```
\overset{\lower.5em\hbox{aaa}}{bbb}
```

Comment: I guess it's useful to know what "works fine for me" may mean in practice. I'd say the approach works sort of ok for minor vertical adjustments (of 0.4ex or less). Larger vertical adjustment values do *not* actually force the supplemental material closer to the arrow; instead, they just increase the line spacing between the line that precedes the `\overset` expression and the `\overset` expression itself.