# New command to change vertical space in overset doesn't work

Tags: spacing, amsmath, kerning, vertical-spacing

I want to reduce the vertical space between a symbol and a letter that are above each other. I have the following code, using a new command $\oset$ that gives exactly the output I need. But unfortunately I get a compiling error, namely: missing $ inserted. When I use $\overset$ the output is wrong, but the compiler works..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oset}[2]{%
   {\mathop{#2}\limits^{\vbox to -.5\ex@{\kern-\tw@\ex@
    \hbox{\scriptsize #1}\vss}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\oset{\sim}{t}$ gives a compiling error.
$\overset{\sim}{t}$ works, but the $\sim$ too high. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\hbox{$\scriptstyle #1$}`

Comment: to establish link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194798/change-vertical-space-in-overset/194805?noredirect=1#comment1632361_194805 (I assume you got your code from @Mico's answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `\hbox{$\scriptstyle#1$}`. However, there's a better way:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oset}[2]{{\mathpalette\o@set{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\o@set}[2]{\o@@set{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\o@@set}[3]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      $\m@th\o@set@demote{#1}#2$\cr
      \noalign{\vskip0.2pt}
      $\m@th#1#3$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\o@set@demote}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
  \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\oset{\sim}{t}$ versus $\tilde{t}$

\end{document}
```

On the other hand, `\tilde{t}` seems much better.

[image]

For completeness here's how to define `\uset` and `\ouset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents} % for comparison

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oset}[2]{{\mathpalette\o@set{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\uset}[2]{{\mathpalette\u@set{{#1}{#2}}}}
\newcommand{\ouset}[3]{\oset{#1}{\uset{#2}{#3}}}

\newcommand{\o@set}[2]{\o@@set{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\o@@set}[3]{%
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      $\m@th\ou@set@demote{#1}#2$\cr
      \noalign{\vskip0.2pt}
      $\m@th#1#3$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\u@set}[2]{\u@@set{#1}#2}
\newcommand{\u@@set}[3]{%
  \vtop{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      $\m@th#1#3$\cr
      \noalign{\vskip0.6pt}
      $\m@th\ou@set@demote{#1}#2$\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\ou@set@demote}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
  \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\oset{\sim}{t}$ versus $\tilde{t}$

$\uset{x}{t}$ versus $\underaccent{x}{t}$

$\ouset{\sim}{x}{t}$ versus $\underaccent{x}{\tilde{t}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to generalize your \oset into \uset (underset) and \ouset (overunderset), but couldn't quite figure it out. Do you mind also writing these commands?

Comment: @D.R I added it

Comment: thank you. I was playing around, and \ouset{*}{*}{<symbol>} works great with letters, and the plus and minus signs, but there is some asymmetry when I use it on \to or the equal sign. This is not so important for my use cases, but it'd be nice to know why.

Comment: @D.R The bounding box of `\to` is “peculiar”.

Answer (score 2):

Remember: it is possible to use also [`mtpro2`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mtp2lite) (I like very much this package), *lite version*. Here there are several examples in relation to your tastes for the lenghts of the tilde symbol. The vertical spacing is automatic.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[
\tilde t+\wtilde t +\wwtilde t+\widetilde t
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `\accentset` command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

$\accentset{\sim}{t}$ compared to $ \tilde{t} $ and to $\widetilde{t}$

\end{document}
```

[image]