# horizontal alignement (leftalign kind) with underset/overset

Tags: math-mode, spacing, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, overset

I am trying to write something like `\underset{\mathbb{P}}{foo}`
where the beginning of `foo` would be horizontally aligned with the P of `\mathbb{P}`, even if 'foo' can be wide (let's say, something like `A \leftarrow \{0,1\} \cup \{5,6\}`). In other words : I am trying to have a `leftalign` option for `underset`.

Moreover, I would be happy if this tip can be compatible with the `\oset` and `\uset` macro defined in
[Change vertical space in overset](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194798/change-vertical-space-in-overset), that allows to control the vertical space.

The only solution I actually found is to manually add horizontal spaces, but the amount of space I need to add is dependent on the content in the `underset` command, so it takes a lot of time when I need to use a lot of them.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose this `\lunderset` that takes as optional argument the separation between the main object and the subscript (default 1pt).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lunderset}[3][1pt]{%
  \binrel@{#3}%
  \binrel@@{%
    \vbox{%
      \offinterlineskip\m@th
      \ialign{##\hfil\cr$\displaystyle#3$\cr\noalign{\vskip#1}$\scriptstyle#2$\cr}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\lunderset{\mathbb{P}}{A\gets\{0,1\}\cup\{5,6\}}
\]

\[
\lunderset[0pt]{\mathbb{P}}{A\gets\{0,1\}\cup\{5,6\}}
\]

\[
\lunderset{\mathbb{P}}{f\gets\{0,1\}\cup\{5,6\}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you plan to use this also inline, using `\displaystyle` is not the best, but this requires some more work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\lunderset}[3][1pt]{%
  \binrel@{#3}%
  \binrel@@{\mathpalette\lunderset@{{#1}{#2}{#3}}}%
}
\newcommand{\lunderset@}[2]{\lunderset@@#1#2}
\newcommand{\lunderset@@}[4]{%
  \vbox{%
    \offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{##\hfil\cr$#1#4$\cr\noalign{\vskip#2}$\lunderset@size{#1}#3$\cr}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\lunderset@size}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\scriptstyle\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\scriptstyle\else
  \scriptscriptstyle\fi\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\lunderset{\mathbb{P}}{A\gets\{0,1\}\cup\{5,6\}}
\]

\[
\lunderset[0pt]{\mathbb{P}}{A\gets\{0,1\}\cup\{5,6\}}
\]

\[
\lunderset{\mathbb{P}}{f\gets\{0,1\}\cup\{5,6\}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it right now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro `\lunderset` (left underset) that uses `\mathrlap` from the `mathtools` package together with a `phantom` of the main content.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}

\newcommand{\lunderset}[2]{\underset{\mathrlap{#1}}{\mathrlap{#2}}\phantom{#2}}

\begin{document}

Some text $\lunderset{\mathbb{P}}{A \leftarrow \{0,1\} \cup \{5,6\}}$ more text

\end{document}
```

This is compatible with [Mico's linked solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194805/125871) for `\uset`, except in your usage the main content shouldn't be contained in `\mathrel`. So use the following:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\uset}[3][0ex]{%
  {\mathop{#3}\limits_{
    \vbox to#1{\kern-7\ex@
    \hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}\vss}}}}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I like the simplicity of it!  I read this article, quoted by  the mathtools documentation, [pdf about alignement macros](https://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb22-4/tb72perlS.pdf), and I think it helped me to understand the general idea! If you have nice references like this one to understand more the alignements in latex, I would be very happy.